# Not sure why this rigid body push script ain't working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I have this rigid body push script but when I apply it on my character it won't push anything.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Push : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Push Settings")]

    [Range(-10.0f, 100.0f)]
    public float PushPower = 10.0f;
    [Range(-10.0f, 10.0f)]
    public float PushDistance = 2.8f;
    public Animator animator;
    Vector3 Direction;
    private bool ObjectMoving = false;

    private bool CanPush = false;


    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
        PushAction();
    }

    private void PushAction()
    {
        // if object moving and player is pressing F key, animation will start.
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.F))
        {
            CanPush = true;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.F))
        {
            CanPush = false;
            ObjectMoving = false;
            animator.SetBool("pushing", false); // deactivating the push animation
        }

        if (ObjectMoving)
        {
            animator.SetBool("pushing", true); // activating the push animation
        }
    }

    private void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
    {
        Rigidbody Body = hit.collider.attachedRigidbody;

        // no rigidbody
        if (Body == null || Body.tag != "Pushable") { return; } // check tag

        // We dont want to push objects below us
        if (hit.moveDirection.y < -0.3) { return; }

        // object won't rotate
        Body.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().freezeRotation = true;

        // calculating player between object distance
        float Dist = Vector3.Distance(Body.gameObject.transform.position, this.transform.position);
        // Debug.Log(Dist);

        // Calculate push direction from move direction,
        // we only push objects to the sides never up and down
        Vector3 PushDirection = new Vector3(hit.moveDirection.x, 0, hit.moveDirection.z);


        // Apply the push
        if (CanPush && Dist < PushDistance)
        {
            Body.isKinematic = false;
            Push.ApplyForceToReachVelocity(Body, PushDirection.normalized * PushPower, 0.1f);
            ObjectMoving = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ObjectMoving = false;
            Body.isKinematic = true;
            Body.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().freezeRotation = false;
        }

        // if object is moving, it is calling to the animation.
        if (Body.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.magnitude > 0.01f)
        {
            ObjectMoving = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ObjectMoving = false;
        }
    }


    // physics library Source: https://gist.github.com/ditzel/1f207c838f0023fcbd34c5c67955fd25
    private static void ApplyForceToReachVelocity(Rigidbody rigidbody, Vector3 velocity, float force = 1, ForceMode mode = ForceMode.Force)
    {
        if (force == 0 || velocity.magnitude == 0)
            return;

        velocity = velocity + velocity.normalized * 0.2f * rigidbody.drag;

        //force = 1 => need 1 s to reach velocity (if mass is 1) => force can be max 1 / Time.fixedDeltaTime
        force = Mathf.Clamp(force, -rigidbody.mass / Time.fixedDeltaTime, rigidbody.mass / Time.fixedDeltaTime);

        if (rigidbody.velocity.magnitude == 0)
        {
            rigidbody.AddForce(velocity * force, mode);
        }
        else
        {
            var velocityProjectedToTarget = (velocity.normalized * Vector3.Dot(velocity, rigidbody.velocity) / velocity.magnitude);
            rigidbody.AddForce((velocity - velocityProjectedToTarget) * force, mode);
        }
    }
}
```

this script is made for triggering an animation upon pushing, for now i just want it to push objects
but is not pushing anything even if the object has the "pushable" tag. Please help me to fix it.Im not able to see what's different from another basic rigid body push script i also got.

Comment: Have you tried to add some debug logs / set breakpoints and see at which point exactly your code maybe behaves different from what you expected? There are some redundancies you could also try to reduce to make your code clearer (e.g. `Body` already **is** a `Rigidbody` so why use `GetComponent`? - at various places you set `ObjectMoving` and independently you set `Body.isKinematic` and `animator.SetBool` .. I would group those in a method so they are always in sync)